# Oldest Linux machine you still run

Tags: kernel, install, distributions, version

What is your oldest machine you ever installed Linux on and currently still run? What are the specs, kernel version or distro, and for what purpose?

Comment: This should probably be a community wiki

Comment: This should probably be on a discussion forum.

Comment: Agree with @postfuturist. This is neither a problem nor an advice request.

Comment: @Hugo, could be useful as a reference to which old device is still usable today. (Say, I'm wondering if I can do something with my old 486).

Comment: I found topic fascinating. Too bad I cannot share my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I installed redhat 5 on my 486 $many years ago.

Oldest machine I have running currently (openbsd at the moment) is an old grey dell optiplex I found in a plie of scrap at the University I went to. It's been running as my network router/firewall/wireless bridge/DNS server for three years now.

```
OpenBSD 4.7 (GENERIC) #558: Wed Mar 17 20:46:15 MDT 2010
    deraadt@i386.openbsd.org:/usr/src/sys/arch/i386/compile/GENERIC
cpu0: Intel Celeron ("GenuineIntel" 686-class, 128KB L2 cache) 399 MHz
real mem  = 265568256 (253MB)
```

Answer (score 1):

SLS distribution, Linux kernel v0.9 1992 era on a 386sx 16Mhz w/16MB RAM

Comment: me too. 16 MHz turbo, 8 MHz normal

Comment: what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

this isn't exactly old but it's interesting, and slow like it was old hardware

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo 
  system type       : TI AR7 (TNETD7200)
  processor     : 0
  cpu model     : MIPS 4KEc V4.8
  BogoMIPS      : 211.35
  wait instruction  : yes
  microsecond timers    : yes
  tlb_entries       : 16
  extra interrupt vector: yes
  hardware watchpoint   : yes
  ASEs implemented  :
  shadow register sets  : 1
  core          : 0
  VCED exceptions   : not available
  VCEI exceptions   : not available
```

- that's about 211MHz CPU
- kernel version 2.6.32.10
- 16MB of RAM
- 4MB of flash
- no:

  - hard drive
  - screen
  - video card
- it has a built in ADSL Modem that powers my Internet
- Distro is [OpenWRT](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/d-link/dsl-502t-genii)

Comment: I have tomato on an old Linksys wireless router.  Also not terribly old (from around 2005), but it's interesting to use `vi`, `ash`, etc in such a limited environment..

Comment: I have it routing native IPv6 as well, yeah the power is amazing for such a small machine, but the 4MB of flash is a little small to do anything else

Answer (score 0):

I have a HP Visualize C3000 from around 1999/2000, it was given to me last week. I have no reason to run it other than to tinker.

- PA8500 400mhz processor
- 2Gb Ram
- SCSI HDD
- Linux Debian 2.6.26-2-parisc

  # cat /proc/cpuinfo
      processor   : 0
      cpu family  : PA-RISC 2.0
      cpu     : PA8500 (PCX-W)
      cpu MHz     : 400.000000
      model       : 9000/785/C3000
      model name  : AllegroHigh W
      hversion    : 0x00005bb0
      sversion    : 0x00000481
      I-cache     : 512 KB
      D-cache     : 1024 KB (WB, direct mapped)
      ITLB entries    : 160
      DTLB entries    : 160 - shared with ITLB
      BTLB        : not supported
      bogomips    : 798.72
      software id : 2014670675

Comment: That's a lot of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 400MHz Dell box (K6 CPU, I think) from circa 1999.  I've run Slackwares up to about 12.0 on it, but last summer, I put Slackware 3.2 on it, just to see what it felt like with a contemporary Linux.

Very interesting.  I had to recompile the kernel (2.0.xx) to get support for a 3c905 ethernet card, and I recompiled XFree86 to get ATI card support.  I was able to complie the latests OpenSSH with only a few glitches for remote access.

Answer (score 0):

I ran [CRUX](http://crux.nu/) on a Compaq Armada with a Pentium MMX 166 MHz, 64 MiB of RAM and an around 2-3 GiB hard disk.  Booted into an XFce desktop in less than 1 minute!

Just for kicks, I also installed Ubuntu 5.04 on that machine once (the whole thing, running a full GNOME install, Firefox, etc.).  That was somewhat slow though...  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The oldest machine that I currently have installed is an old HP Pavilion desktop that I picked up from a repossession for $20. It's my main web, DNS, DHCP, NFS, CUPS and SSH server as well as firewall and gateway.

```
<<< 21:43.02 Mon Aug 23 2010|~
<<< aaron@achilles (Linux 2.6.26-2-686)|8171 screen:2
>>> cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 8
model name      : Celeron (Coppermine)
stepping        : 6
cpu MHz         : 697.894
cache size      : 128 KB
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f0f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 2
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 mmx fxsr sse up
bogomips        : 1397.85
clflush size    : 32
power management:
```

It has 512MB of RAM with 100GB hard drive space. It's running Debian GNU/Linux stable. Kernel version is in the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The one I'm currently running on is reasonably old.

```
processor    : 0
vendor_id    : GenuineIntel
cpu family   : 6
model        : 8
model name   : Pentium III (Coppermine)
stepping     : 10
cpu MHz      : 1004.123
cache size   : 256 KB
fdiv_bug     : no
hlt_bug      : no
f00f_bug     : no
coma_bug     : no
fpu          : yes
fpu_exception : yes
cpuid level  : 2
wp           : yes
flags        : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 sep mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 mmx fxsr sse up
bogomips     : 2009.92
clflush size : 32
cache_alignment : 32
address sizes: 36 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
power management:
```

384 MB RAM, less than 80 GB hard drive. Currently running Debian Testing. I once installed AntiX (based on Debian) on it, and it felt far newer than it is, but then I began to miss my GNOME environment.